# threads in cpp is giving error

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(processVideo, "video1.mp4");
    std::thread t2(processVideo, "video1.mp4");
    // Makes the main thread wait for the new thread to finish execution, therefore blocks its own execution.
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    destroyAllWindows();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void processVideo(char* videoFilename) {
//process the video file
}
```

Whenever I run the code, I get the following error:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(240): error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found

1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(240): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'

1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(240): note: With the following template arguments:

1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(240): note: '_Callable=void (__cdecl *)(char *)'

1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(240): note: '_Types={const char *}'

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried to add

```
std::thread t1(processVideo,this, "video1.mp4");
```

but it is giving me error while compiling.

This only be used inside a nonstatic member function.

Comment: Try to pass `&processVideo` instead to the thread

Comment: I would think that defining the thread function with a const parameter would work: `void processVideo(const char* const videoFilename)` or even better: `void processVideo(const std::string& videoFilename)`

Comment: @stefaanv you should post this as an answer: http://ideone.com/ay0n7W

Comment: I didn't think it was up to standards to be an answers because it lacks explanation and I wasn't completely sure about all the details, so if anyone will give a descent answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `void processVideo(char* videoFilename)` takes a non-const `char*`.

The string `"video1.mp4"` is a `const char*`, which is incompatible with the function.

The error messages actually indicate this, but it's hard to see the wood for the trees.